# How to access multiple tables from a SELECT FROM in ASP.NET with SQL Server?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database

I have this project I am working on for an assignment, and I have a question working with ASP.NET and SQL Server. I have a login page that kinda works, but there are two tables that I need to get data from - users (`subscribers`) and admin page but am unsure how to access both of them as I can only access one.

```
public void login(Object src,EventArgs e)
{
    get_connection();

    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM subscribers WHERE Email = @Email AND Password = @Password", connection);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", loginName.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", loginPass.Text);

        //command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE Email =@Email and Password = @Password", connection);
        //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", loginName.Text);
        //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", loginPass.Text);

        reader = command.ExecuteReader();
```

I commented out the admin part because when I include it, only admin username and password is accepted and not subscribers. What would I need to do to fix this?

Comment: If schemas are the same and you don't want to make two cmd instance, you can `UNION` the SELECTs.

Answer (score 1):

The "admin part" causes you to only get records from the admin table because you're destroying and recreating your SqlCommand object. You'll need to create a new command in a different variable and read from it separately. There are ways to get multiple recordsets in the same call but I don't recommend it in this case.

That out of the way...  Normally I'd expect to see a single users table with permissions/roles granted elsewhere. Consider something like the out of the box ASP.NET membership provider to take care of these implementation details for you:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-use-the-aspnet-membership-provider